# "Besides" is inclusive, "except" is exclusive

Tags: prepositions

> Besides is inclusive, whereas except is exclusive, so that ***Besides**
> Larry, we'll invite John, Jake, and Rene* means that *Larry* is also
> invited.

OED says

> [**BESIDES**](https://oed.com/oed2/00020842) Preposition 3. Other than, else than: *in negative
> and interrogative (**formerly** sometimes in affirmative)* sentences,
> capable of being rendered by ‘except, excluding.’ (Cf. [except](https://oed.com/oed2/00079534) : Preposition †2.
> Leaving out of account; hence, in addition to, **besides**, as well
> as. **Obs. rare**.)

[Page 593 of the CambridgeGEL](https://es1lib.org/book/5606200/f71243) reads

> [62] i) a. Kim too resigned. b. Only Kim resigned. ii) a. “Kim
> resigned” b. “Kim resigned” iii) a. “Someone besides Kim resigned” b.
> “No one except Kim resigned.” Both [ia] and [ib] entail that Kim
> resigned: the obvious difference between additive too and restrictive
> only is shown in [iii]. But there is also a difference with respect to
> the status of the component propositions given in [ii–iii]. We saw
> that with only the main assertion is [iiib], with [iib] being
> backgrounded. With too, however, it is [iia] that is the main
> assertion, and [iiia] that is backgrounded. And in fact [iiia] (unlike
> [iib]) is not an entailment, not a truth condition, but merely a
> conventional implicature. The only scenario in which [ia] can be false
> is one where Kim didn’t resign. To see more easily that this is so,
> consider a situation in the future. You say Pat will sign the cheque
> and I respond Kim too will sign it. And suppose that in fact Pat does
> not sign, and only Kim does so: it is clear that the prediction I made
> will be judged to have turned out to be true, not false. Correlating
> with this is a difference with respect to negation. We have seen that
> negating [62ib] affects [iiib]: Not only Kim resigned says that there
> was someone else besides Kim who resigned. But we can’t negate [ia] so
> as to cancel [iiia], while leaving [iia] intact. ∗Not Kim too resigned
> is ungrammatical, and Kim too didn’t resign has too outside the scope
> of negation, so that the two components are “Kim didn’t resign” and
> “Someone besides Kim didn’t resign”.

However, most native speakers interpret *Everyone besides Larry was invited* to mean *Larry* was **not** invited. Why is it so?

Comment: In the definition you quoted -- the first definition, actually, besides = other than. So, in the sentence "Everyone besides Larry was invited," it means everyone **other than** Larry was invited. Obviously, Larry was not invited. I can't speak for BrE, but that's the way it is in AmE.

Comment: @FeliniusRex OTHER THAN only applies _in negative and interrogative (formerly sometimes in affirmative) sentences_, so a negative polarity term

Comment: OP -- The definition you quoted goes on to say "capable of being rendered by ‘except, excluding.'". If you're talking about "negative polarity terms" you're probably not in the right place. I guess I could look up what those are, but apparently I haven't needed to know that to grasp the obvious meaning of *besides* here.

Comment: [Why is *that* so?] **besides in that sentence means except for**, See Merriam Webster. First definition. And except for = the OED's meaning of **other than**.  Everyone besides Larry or except for Larry or other than Larry was invited. All mean the same thing. Your inclusive/exclusive thing is wrong.

Comment: For those who find the above hard to read because of poor formatting, I have cleaned up [the identical question on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/569965/26083).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the very definition you linked to:

> 2. Over and above, in addition to, as well as

is inclusive

> 3. Other than, else than: in negative and interrogative (formerly sometimes in affirmative) sentences, capable of being rendered by ‘except, excluding.’

is exclusive

Comment: I meant not to agree. It means except for Larry. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GJC You seem to be ignoring my comment. So be it.

Comment: @GJC Look at your link dude. It has that definition for _both_ the preposition and adverb